# Installing multer-gridfs-storage package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-package

After running npm i multer-gridfs-storage i am getting this in my terminal.
How to resolve my problem?
npm i multer-gridfs-storage
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: multer@1.4.5-lts.1
npm ERR! node_modules/multer
npm ERR!   multer@"^1.4.5-lts.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer multer@"^1.4.2" from multer-gridfs-storage@5.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/multer-gridfs-storage
npm ERR!   multer-gridfs-storage@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:

Expecting it to be installed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your error message properly and use backticks ("```") for code & message blocks. Complete the tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)